# Choosing desired rows in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a data of 9 columns 14470 rows,
The first column is filled with 0 or 1. Zero means that there is no measurment and the whole row is not in my interest.... can some body help me in writing a loop which go through all lines and filter the data when in first column 1 exist?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a loop for this, remember Matlab is a matrix oriented programming language, loops should be avoided. I won't give you the answer, I think you can figure it out yourself, it's easy. This [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/yagtom/) will help.

Have fun.